# How to assert 2 keys in many objects

Tags: karate

response =

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    modelId: "301",
    modelName: "x",
    trimId: "301",
    trimName: "up!",
    derivativeName: "xx",
    fuelType: "PETROL",
    tco: {
      price: {
        tco: null,
        retail: 12,
        offer: null,
        subsidy: null,
        residual: null
      },
      milesPerYear: 10000,
      mpg: 51.5,
      fuelCost: 1.1,
      milesPerKW: 0,
      monthsOfOwnership: 48,
      energyCost: 12,
      tax: 42,
      comparable: false
    }
  },
  {
    id: "1239",
    modelId: "301",
    modelName: "up!",
    trimId: "301",
    trimName: "x",
    derivativeName: "xx",
    fuelType: "PETROL",
    tco: {
      price: {
        tco: null,
        retail: 1,
        offer: null,
        subsidy: null,
        residual: null
      },
      milesPerYear: 10000,
      mpg: 53.2,
      fuelCost: 1.1,
      milesPerKW: 0,
      monthsOfOwnership: 48,
      energyCost: 12,
      tax: 4,
      comparable: false
    }
  }
]
```

Been trying to work this out but can't figure out the best way to do it.

I'm trying to check when the key `fuelType` = PETROL then key `fuelCost` must equal 1.1

There are many objects within the response and I want to assert the 2 keys (fuelType and Fuelcost) in every object.

I tried the following:

```
Given path 'url'
    When method GET
    Then match each response[*] contains {[*].fuelType:PETROL , [*].tco.fuelCost:1.1}
```

Please help
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, adapt if needed:

```
* def isValid = function(x){ return if x.fuelType == 'PETROL' && x.fuelCost == 1.1 }
* match each response == '#? isValid(_)'
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Comment: Hi Peter, I am still having issue trying to assert every element in an array which has no identifier.  So as you can see from the response in the original post, elements are in a [ ] single array.  I have tried the following but it's only asserting the top level element. ``` * def isValid = function(x) { return response[0].fuelType == "PETROL" && response[0].tco.price.tco == null}
    * match each response === '#? isValid(_)'```

Comment: And the following gives a operand error : ``` * def isValid = function(x) { return response[*].fuelType == "PETROL" && response[*].tco.price.tco == null}
    * match each response === '#? isValid(_)' ```

Comment: @PaulD to be honest I have not read your example because it is too big. please create a simple (bare minimum) example and ask another question, read this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve